# How to make a bootstrap popover sticky and how to hide it with the right timing?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

i am currently working on project where i have to let something pop up when i hover the element and after releasing the element it should hide after some time, but if i hover the popover itself the timer should stop and the popover shouldnt hide.

So i tried it with a simple timer which gets activated after releasing the element who triggers the popover, and when i hover the popover the timer gets stopped. But some Problems occured when doing this. I got a lot of Elements to hover and when i hover them all in a short time, timer gets overwritten and nothing worked like it should.

So i implemented a specific timer for every element that i hover. I assigned the id of my element to a data-attribute inside my popover, so i know which popover belongs to which element.When i hover the element, the popover will be displayed. when i release the element,timer gets started and the timer-id gets assigend to a data-attr inside my hovered element. When i now hover my popover, i get the corresponding elemnt-id out of my popover which got the corresponding timer id and then i clear this specific timer.
But it doesnt work, when hovering and releasing one of the elements slowly everything seems to work, but if go a little bit faster between the elements that i can hover some problems occure. The popover sometimes just hide randomly after some seconds.
i cant find what i am doing wrong ? it would be awesome if someone knows how to do it better. 
CODE:

```
$(".timelineTour")
         .popover({
             offset: 10,
             trigger: 'manual',
             animate: false,
             html: true,
             placement: 'right',
             template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); }); console.log(\'mouseover popover\');"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'



        }).mouseenter(function(){
          $('.timelineTour').not($(this)).popover('hide');
          $(this).popover('show');

        }).mouseleave(function(){
          var current = this;
          var t = window.setTimeout(function(){
          $(current).popover('hide');},1000);
          $(current).attr("data-timer",t);
        });

        $(".popover").live("mouseenter",function () { 
             var k = $(this).find('.popoverContent').attr("data-tour-id");
             var z = $('#'+k).attr("data-timer");
             window.clearTimeout(z);      
         });
```